# iphone simulator(10.3) time not showing according to timezone in mac OS (10.13)

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, xcode8, macos-high-sierra

I have update my mac os to 10.13 beta version now it showing GMT time for my old simulator with ios version 10.3. its not displaying as per mytimezone(IST). even after reset it and region change of simulator its continuous showing GMT time only. [image]

Comment: Just started running into this today.

Comment: I am seeing this, too. The simulator's time zone is GMT for some reason. I'm still investigating.

Comment: yeah this issue occur on Mac OS 10.13

Comment: yes. but due to this during developing not able to get local time.

Comment: I have fixed it , you can see it in below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple says there are currently no plans to fix this, as per http://www.openradar.me/34812060

Answer (score 1):

This fixed for me :

```
export TIMEZONE="Australia/Sydney"
sudo rm -rf /etc/localtime 
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TIMEZONE /etc/localtime
```