# iOS 10.3 simulator display wrong time (UTC instead of Local timezone) in macOS High Sierra

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, datetime, ios-simulator

After many research, I didn't find any working solution. I don't know why my iOS 10.3 simulator display wrong time (UTC instead of Local timezone) in macOS High Sierra (after setup also). I have applied to many solutions to it but nothing works for me. I have attached a screenshot of same.

Ref. link https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93087

So, kindly help me on this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This is a known bug.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46253736/1402846

Comment: I am also facing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **updating** my **Xcode 8 to Xcode 9**, above issue has been resolved automatically.